# Why does this rewrite in NGINX not work?

Tags: php, nginx

Trying to add a rewrite in local sever but I'm stuck.

This is what I have.

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /news/post/ {
        rewrite ^/news/post/([a-zA-Z0-9-])?$ /news/post.php?id=$1 break;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #extra
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #--extra
    }
```

When going to /news/post/ it says "You have chosen to open this file" and ask if I want to download a BIN file.

If I go to /news/post/this-is-a-news-title I get a 404 Not Found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow: Why would anyone vote down a question? What's the point of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works. Changed a bit and needed the full path.

```
location /news/post/ {
        rewrite ^/news/post/(.*)$ http://www.myserver.com/news/post.php?id=$1 break;
    }
```